# NSMutableDictionary hash (hashCode) values are the same for different objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c, hash, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

Here's an example of two different dictionaries, yet they return the same hash code.  Why?

https://gist.github.com/837861

(They aren't the same object)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hashes aren't guaranteed to be distinct for distinct objects. In fact, hash collisions will happen. The only two properties the [`-hash`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/hash) method is supposed to guarantee are (both taken from the documentation):

- If two objects are equal (as determined by the isEqual: method), they must have the same hash value.
- If a mutable object is added to a collection that uses hash values to determine the object’s position in the collection, the value returned by the hash method of the object must not change while the object is in the collection.

Comment: The guarantees are: 1) Objects with different hashes are not the same, and 2) An object will have the same hash as itself. It is actually valid (though an awful idea, practically speaking) to have every object hash to the number 5.

Comment: So I guess the logical conclusion is: if objects aren't equal, then they won't necessarily have different hash values (but may).

Answer (score 1):

If you look here, you can see that the hash implementation on dictionaries simply returns the count and is likely the reason why you're getting the same code:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984624/59198