# Hash value of NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

I ran into an issue, where I got the same hash value for different dictionaries. Maybe I'm doing something obvious wrong, but I thought, objects with different content (a.k.a. not equal objects) should have different hash values.

```
NSDictionary *dictA = @{ @"foo" : @YES };
NSDictionary *dictB = @{ @"foo" : @NO };

BOOL equal = [dictA hash] == [dictB hash];

NSAssert(!equal, @"Assuming, that different dictionaries have different hash values.");
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The hash being equal does not imply the objects are equal.

Comment: `if ([dictA isEqualToDictionary:dictB)`

Comment: I know, that the mapping from an object to a hash is not a one to one mapping, and that there might be different objects with the same hash value, but I thought, this is only a really rare case.

Comment: @janusfidel I don't want to compare the objects for equality. I wanted to use the value for something else.

Comment: Maybe the **hash** is based only on the keys of the dictionary?

Comment: @MarkusHardt Tried it with different keys and also creating NSNumber objects _by hand_. Both values are _1_.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no guarantee that two different objects will have different hash values.

In the latest [open-source version of CoreFoundation](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.21/CFDictionary.c), the hash of a CFDictionary (which is equivalent to an NSDictionary) is defined as:

```
static CFHashCode __CFDictionaryHash(CFTypeRef cf) {
    return __CFBasicHashHash((CFBasicHashRef)cf);
}
```

[and `__CFBasicHashHash` is defined as](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-635.21/CFBasicHash.m):

```
__private_extern__ CFHashCode __CFBasicHashHash(CFTypeRef cf) {
    CFBasicHashRef ht = (CFBasicHashRef)cf;
    return CFBasicHashGetCount(ht);
}
```

which is simply the number of entries stored in the collection. In the other words, both `[dictA hash]` and `[dictB hash]`'s hash value are **1**, the number of entries in the dictionaries.

While it is a very bad hash algorithm, CF didn't do anything wrong here. If you need to have a more accurate hash value, you can provide one yourself in an Obj-C category.

Comment: „While it is a very bad hash algorithm,…“ This for sure. I guess I have to work around this in my case. Thanks.

Comment: **There is a very good reason it is implemented this way.** As NSArray is immutable, it's [-copy] returns self. If it would be e.g. added to a dictionary as a key, the hash should never change, even if the objects in the array are mutated.

Comment: @Patrick Well the "sum of the first 32 pointer values of the array" is also immutable. The only good reason is that it's extremely fast to compute, or since hardly anyone uses an NSDictionary as a key let's not create a complicated hash.

Comment: @kennytm, well, "sum of the first 32 pointer values of the array" is indeed immutable - but then you may end up with two equal array objects with two different hash values which would violate hash/isEqual invariant.

for example:
`NSArray<NSNumber *> *arr1 = @[@(3)];`
`NSArray<NSNumber *> *arr2 = @[@(3.000)];`

they are isEqual, but if we use your hash-scheme (first 32 pointer values), their hash values would differ (because @(3) and @(3.000) have different pointer values)

Answer (score 5):

With a dictionary with only integers, strings etc. I would use `dict.description.hash` as a quick code.

Comment: Then dictionaries with same contents but different ordering would result in different hashes.

Comment: nice trick, better than nothing, but still...

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on [igor-kulagin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1050261/igor-kulagin)'s answer which is not order dependent:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (Extensions)

- (NSUInteger) hash
{
    NSUInteger prime = 31;
    NSUInteger result = 1;
    for (NSObject *key in [[self allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]) {
        result = prime * result + [key hash];
        result = prime * result + [self[key] hash];
    }
    return result;
}
@end
```

However, there is still a possibility of collision if the dictionary contains other dictionaries as values.

Answer (score 1):

The function 'hash' is not a real hash function.  It gives different values for strings (all predictable) but for collections (arrays and dictionaries) it just returns the count.  If you want a unique hash you can calculate it yourself using primes, or the functions srandom() and random() or explore a real hash function like SHA1 available in CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h

Answer (score -1):

I created **NSDictionary** category and overridden **hash** method based on this answer: [Best practices for overriding isEqual: and hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254281/best-practices-for-overriding-isequal-and-hash)

```
@implementation NSDictionary (Extensions)

- (NSUInteger) hash {
    NSUInteger prime = 31;
    NSUInteger result = 1;

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [self.allKeys sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
    for (NSObject *key in sortedKeys) {
        result = prime * result + key.hash;
        id value = self[key];
        if ([value conformsToProtocol: @protocol(NSObject)] == YES) {
            result = prime * result + [value hash];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

And Swift implementation.

```
extension Dictionary where Key: Comparable, Value: Hashable {
    public var hashValue: Int {
        let prime = 31
        var result = 1

        let sortedKeys = self.keys.sorted()
        for (key) in sortedKeys {
            let value = self[key]!
            result = Int.addWithOverflow(Int.multiplyWithOverflow(prime, result).0, key.hashValue).0
            result = Int.addWithOverflow(Int.multiplyWithOverflow(prime, result).0, value.hashValue).0
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Perfectly this also requires to implement `Equatable` protocol for `Dictionary` so you can also add `Hashable` protocol conformance.

Comment: this might return different hash values for the same hash, since the ordering of the keys might change. a better solution is to order the keys first.