# How to find the origin of a function call that is leading to crash in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, ipad

My iPad app which is written in Objective C is crashing on method that is on NSDictionary Category which is in written inside a framework (I have only header files in the framework). I am not calling that category method anywhere but it somehow gets called and it is crashing with unrecognised selector sent to instance. I would like to find the origin of the call that is made which is leading to this. Is there any way we can do that?

It is crashing only on iOS14 and works fine on below versions of iOS. Any help is much appreciated.

**UPDATED WITH CRASH LOG** - NSDictionary(NSDictionary_SA_Additions) is category inside a framework which I mentioned earlier.

```
2020-08-27 11:00:03.017073+0100 MyApp[5881:81328] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConstantIntegerNumber characterAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff86cc4850'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20439dee __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff20177f78 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2044893f +[NSObject(NSObject) instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:] + 0
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2043e32e ___forwarding___ + 1489
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20440368 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff207c2b1f -[NSDictionary(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 79
    6   MyApp                               0x0000000101b645fd -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary_SA_Additions) SA_md5Hash] + 397
    7   MyApp                               0x0000000101b64646 -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary_SA_Additions) SA_md5Hash] + 470
    8   MyApp                               0x0000000101b6445b -[NSDictionary(NSDictionary_SA_Additions) hash] + 43
    9   libcache.dylib                      0x00007fff53be7bc7 _entry_get_optionally_checking_collisions + 42
    10  libcache.dylib                      0x00007fff53be6097 cache_get + 128
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20465132 -[NSCache objectForKey:] + 152
    12  CoreText                            0x00007fff21000ed2 _ZN15TPurgeableCache19RetainedValueForKeyEPKv + 54
    13  CoreText                            0x00007fff210b192e _ZN12TCGFontCache21CopyFontWithVariationEP6CGFontPK14__CFDictionary + 1694
    14  CoreText                            0x00007fff210813e4 _ZNK29TTenuousComponentInstanceFont16CopyGraphicsFontEv + 150
    15  CoreText                            0x00007fff20fdf98b _ZNK9TBaseFont26GetInitializedGraphicsFontEv + 63
    16  CoreText                            0x00007fff2106ca11 _ZNK9TBaseFont13GetParserFontEv + 9
    17  CoreText                            0x00007fff21054284 _ZNK10TcmapTable8MapRangeE7CFRangePt + 42
    18  CoreText                            0x00007fff21072c20 _ZNK9TBaseFont26GetGlyphsForCharacterRangeE7CFRangePt + 94
    19  CoreText                            0x00007fff2107eab8 _ZNK14TComponentFont26GetGlyphsForCharacterRangeE7CFRangePt + 278
    20  CoreText                            0x00007fff20fc884a _ZN15TASCIIDataCacheC2EPK5TFont + 78
    21  CoreText                            0x00007fff20fdd430 _ZNK5TFont18InitASCIIDataCacheEv + 34
    22  CoreText                            0x00007fff20fcf9d0 CTFontGetLatin1GlyphsAndAdvanceWidths + 51
    23  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff239e0268 -[NSCoreTypesetter _NSFastDrawString:length:attributes:paragraphStyle:typesetterBehavior:lineBreakMode:rect:padding:graphicsContext:baselineRendering:usesFontLeading:usesScreenFont:scrollable:syncAlignment:mirrored:boundingRectPointer:baselineOffsetPointer:drawingContext:] + 1821
    24  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff239e1b0b -[NSCoreTypesetter _stringDrawingCoreTextEngineWithOriginalString:rect:padding:graphicsContext:forceClipping:attributes:stringDrawingOptions:drawingContext:stringDrawingInterface:] + 1278
    25  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff239db738 __NSStringDrawingEngine + 2887
    26  UIFoundation                        0x00007fff239dabc7 -[NSString(NSExtendedStringDrawing) boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:] + 187
    27  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ae3d10 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 4020
    28  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ae0ff7 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 1061
    29  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ae3e42 -[UILabel drawRect:] + 71
    30  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24ba1c85 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:] + 625
    31  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a7830d -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 288
    32  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27935321 CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 190
    33  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a819b9 ___ZN2CA5Layer8display_Ev_block_invoke + 53
    34  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a77b4a -[CALayer _display] + 2111
    35  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a8b327 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 463
    36  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff279cb3d4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionEdPd + 496
    37  QuartzCore                          0x00007fff27a02163 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 783
    38  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff246656a0 __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 81
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a834b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    40  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a775f __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 434
    41  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a217c __CFRunLoopRun + 899
    42  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff203a190e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 567
    43  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff2ba85db3 GSEventRunModal + 139
    44  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff24647ffd -[UIApplication _run] + 912
    45  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff2464cf0e UIApplicationMain + 101
    46  MyApp                               0x000000010177f16e main + 78
    47  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20257415 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConstantIntegerNumber characterAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fff86cc4850'
CoreSimulator 732.13 - Device: iPad Air (3rd generation) (C762993D-AFF7-412A-89AF-92DB600B2153) - Runtime: iOS 14.0 (18A5351d) - DeviceType: iPad Air (3rd generation)
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: There is no stacktrace in console when it's crashing? What's the full error message in console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting. It seems based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11984624/5329717) the genuine hash function of `CFDictionary` / `NSDictionary` is as basic as it gets (the computed hash value is number of elements in a dictionary). That would lead to A LOT of collisions if someone wanted to have a dictionary using `NSDictionary` as a key. Seems a plausible reason to override the stock hash function through the `NSDictionary_SA_Additions` category with the `SA_md5Hash` implementation.

I think next step would be to investigate iOS14 hash function of `NSDictionary` (with different values inside) vs previous iOS versions.

I imagine a potential fix could be restoring the hash function of `NSDictionary` if detected running iOS14 provided the troublesome framework would keep working correctly.

UPDATE:
You cannot revert a category. But you can override it through swizzling.

```
#include <objc/message.h>
__attribute__((constructor))
static void premain() {
    SEL hashSelector = @selector(hash);
    Method method = class_getClassMethod([NSDictionary class], hashSelector);
    const char * encoding = method_getTypeEncoding(method);
    IMP newHashImplementation = imp_implementationWithBlock(^NSUInteger (NSDictionary* self, SEL __cmd){
        return CFDictionaryGetCount((CFDictionaryRef)self);
    });
    class_replaceMethod([NSDictionary class], hashSelector, newHashImplementation, encoding);
}
```

That's a new implementation in spirit of the original one. Unfortunately we cannot get the genuine original one after the category override due to the selector name(`"hash"`) clash. `__attribute__((constructor))` guarantees it's executed as the very 1st thing after your app has completed initiating categories.

*Alternatively* to revert the category in a literal sense a binary modification of the framework is required. Specifically the `__TEXT,__objc_methname`
[image]
[image]
You'd change the `hash` to something else e.g `hasg`. But that's almost certain to be against the license of the framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, can we find out for which dictionary in the code it is trying to override hash function?

Comment: The category hash override is on NSDictonary class level. Hence it affects every single instance of NSDictonary throughout app lifetime. But it’s worth investigating what the hash is exactly used for by the troublesome framework. NSDictionary used as key in a yet another NSDicionary is only a guess from me.

Comment: Let me check it out. But, I am not sure whether I will be able to find out as I have only header files of it and all I could see NSUInteger declaration of SA_md5Hash.

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger SA_md5Hash;

Comment: Is there a way to stop using the framework category?

Comment: This framework is licence free and can be modified. But how will I do the binary modification of this framework and where should I add this code to perform swizzling? Sorry, I m not familiar with these concepts. So, if you could share me some tutorial to do this, it would be very helpful.

Comment: You can put the code anywhere. `main.m` will do if you use objective-c for your project. Modifying the framework binary is a rather extreme alternative, unless you really know what you're doing I discourage it.

Comment: I added the code in main.m and it seems to override the hash function of the framework. Now, it doesn't crash. I am now interested in swizzling and trying to understand how it works. Thanks for your patience and help.

Answer (score 1):

Someone is calling the NSString function characterAtIndex on an object of type NSConstantIntegerNumber, which obviously cannot work.

Unless you feel responsible for somehow setting an integer as a key in a dictionary that expects string keys, I'd file a bug report against iOS 14.